# rails jbuilder adding a root node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have the following jbuilder view:

```
json.array!(@users) do |json, user_object|
    json.partial! "api/v1/users/show", user: user_object
end
```

to show each user data I render a partial of show to avoid duplication. This is all good but I also want to add a root node to the results to indicate some pagination data:

```
{
    total_pages: 1,
    total_records: 1000,
    users: {
        [ ...users here... ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This should give you a root node for the users array:

```
json.users do |json|
    json.array!(@users) do |json, user_object|
        json.partial! "api/v1/users/show", user: user_object
    end
end
```

It should produce:

```
users: [
    { ...user here... },
    { ...user here... },
    etc
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
json.total_pages 1
json.total_records 100
json.users do |usersElement|
  usersElement.array!(@users) do |parent, user|
    parent.partial! "api/v1/users/show", user: user
  end
end
```